# How to get JNDI datasource in Spring Boot from IBM WebSphere 9

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, jndi

Trying to deploy SpringBoot app to WebSphere 9 with using jdbc as SQL Server.
I need to get jdbc username and password from websphere settings (not from app.properties).

As I understand, I can use InitialConfig.lookup() or JndiDataSourceLookup, but how could I find database, username and password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Add the following property into `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/jndiName
```

add datasource bean definition in spring boot main class or config class

```
 @Autowired
 private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate()
                             .lookup(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.jndi-name"));
 }
```

**Option 2:**

using Java standard API

```
DataSource ds = javax.naming.InitialContext.doLookup("jdbc/jndiName");
```

Comment: in that case i got an error: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: Read this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387238/what-does-javax-naming-noinitialcontextexception-mean. As you are using Websphere, You can specify jndi for database through admin console. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tdat_ccrtpds.html

Comment: In the past I referred to below to articles while doing a POC app http://naruraghavan.github.io/deploying-spring-boot-applications-in-ibm-websphere-application-server/
https://support.bp-3.com/hc/en-us/articles/210443048

Comment: done all JNDI config through WAS admin console, rebooted WAS and still got same error and datasource null. What can I do?

Comment: @Roman.77 did you tested jndi through admin console. make sure your jndi in admin console matches with jndi defined in your spring boot app.

Comment: Now it works, after I used  the same jndi name in WAS as jndi name in app. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Roman.77 if you think this answer is solution to problem/question them please accept the answer.